# AngularJS - ngTagsInput autocomplete issue

Tags: json, angularjs, autocomplete, ng-tags-input

I am trying to use the ngTagsInput and it is working except I am unable to read from a json file and display in the autocomplete.

The json is:

```
[
    { "text": "Tag1" }, 
    { "text": "Tag2" }, 
    { "text": "Tag3" }
]
```

I have tried a simple $HTTP.get and am able to read the json file but for some reason it is not being displayed in the input.

I thought it might be an async issue so I tried this:

```
    var d = $q.defer();
    $http.get('data/tags.json').success(function(data){
        d.resolve(data);            
    });
    return d.promise;
```

with which I had the same problem.

Interestingly I *can* get the autocomplete to work with:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
deferred.resolve([{ text: 'Tag9' },{ text: 'Tag10' }]);
return deferred.promise;
```

So am wondering if it is the way my json is formatted.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why don't you do a console.log(data) and then check, what it is showing?

Comment: It is showing the data. [ { text: "Tag1" }, { text: "Tag2" }, { text: "Tag3" }].Getting the data doesn't seem to be the problem, it is either an async issue or a formatting issue.

Comment: OK, don't really know. What I would try is to check if the problem is not related to async nature by putting the static version within a timeout like this.
window.setTimeout(function() {
  deferred.resolve([{text: 'Tag9'}, {text: 'Tag10'}]);
}, 3000);

Comment: Could you provide a plunk or something showing your problem? You can use [this one](http://plnkr.co/edit/bDx54d?p=info) (which has autocomplete working, btw) and modify it at will.

Comment: Could you put the link to this plunk as an answer so I can select it as the right answer. I modified the code and got it working so thanks for that.

Comment: How did you get it working with the promise?

Comment: The code above (deferred.resolve([{ text: 'Tag9' },{ text: 'Tag10' }]);) is correct. The ng-tags input requires that the tags represent the value of the text property. In other words, you need to use the text: tag pattern.

Comment: http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos
this might help you